# Cloud Function Failing to Query BQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My python function is failing to query BQ with this error;
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: URL

However, this is not happening consistently and I can't figure out why.
The cloud functions service account has access to BigQuery and this issue only comes up after what looks to be several hours of inactivity.

This is also a recent issue that started on January 26th.
Has anyone experienced this?

Just to clarify, this block of code does not throw any errors;

```
try:
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
except Exception as e:
    error_message = 'Could not connect to Big Query.'
    print(error_message)
    print(e)
```

It's this part right here;

```
so = pd.read_gbq(get_so_query(so_num), project_id='project1', dialect='standard')
```

Comment: Do you use a serverless VPC connector or other special customization on your function?

Comment: No, nothing besides invoke permissions.

Comment: For using `read_gbq` method you will need to import also the pandas-gbq library. In your Cloud Functions `requirements.txt` you will need to add the [pandas-gbq library](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html). In case you already have it, [here](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html) the different methods for authentication using a service account or the default credentials. In your case, you will need to implement one of the methods with the service account as stated in the link above. I hope it helps.

Comment: Although this is still a bit weird because the first time the function runs after a couple of hours of inactivity, it fails. However, in 5 minutes, it starts working again.

Is it getting the service key and caching it on it's own?

Comment: "Is it getting the service key and caching it on it's own? " It should not be like that. It should get the service key and execute the code in the same call to the function. Make sure to implement one of the different solutions shown [here](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/authentication.html). Also, if it keeps failing, it would be great if you could add the logs when the cloud functions fail to the question. Make sure to sanitized as it may contain sensitive data. I hope it helps.